# Ace.js: different completers for different same-page editors

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have multiple Ace.js editors on the same page, and I'm willing to set their own set of autocompleted words. Is that something possible?

Here is my failed attempt: http://plnkr.co/edit/GTfRjmdDe4dlOvzYh60C?p=preview

As you can see, the last completer used (`langTools.setCompleters([myCompleter2]);`) overwrite previous one.

=> Is it possible to bind a specific completer/language_tools to a specific editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here was the answer : http://plnkr.co/edit/0gXkJDCmbJyG2Amrwvuf?p=preview

It is possible to bind a completer to an editor. Happy wildguessing.

`editor1.completers = [myCompleter1];`

Comment: Thank god I found your comment... this isn't documented anywhere. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: In your answer  it's using this: editor2.completers = [myCompleter2, myCompleter1];